# How do you delete highlighted characters in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, hosts-file

How do you delete highlighted characters in notepad++?

For example, in the below image: 
How do I remove all of the highlighted 1's that are trailing each hosts file entry?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove all `1` at the end of each lines, you could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `1$`   or   `1\h*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
1       : literally "1"
\h*     : 0 or more horizontal spaces
$       : end of line
```